# Make a path where next node is not the previous node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have ~1.5 M nodes in a graph, that are structured like this (picture)

[image: Graph]

I run a Cypher query that performs calculations on each relationship traversed:

```
WITH 1 AS startVal
MATCH x = (c:Currency)-[r:Arb*2]->(m)
WITH x, REDUCE(s = startVal, e IN r | s * e.rate) AS endVal, startVal
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(x) | n) as Exchanges,
    extract ( e IN relationships(x) | startVal * e.rate) AS Rel,
    endVal, endVal - startVal AS Profit
ORDER BY Profit DESC LIMIT 5
```

The problem is it returns the path `("One")->("hop")->("One")`, which is useless for me.

How can I make it not choose the previously walked node as the next node (i.e. `"One"->"hop"->"any_other_node_but_not_"one"`)?

I have read that `NODE_RECENT` should address my issue. However, there was no example on how to specify the length of recent nodes in RestAPI or APOC procedures.

Is there a Cypher query for my case?

Thank you.

P.S. I am extremely new (less than 2 month) to Neo4j and coding. So my apologies if there is an obvious simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting this clause after your `MATCH` clause, to filter out cases where `c` and `m` are the same:

```
WHERE c <> m
```

[EDITED]

That is:

```
WITH 1 AS startVal
MATCH x = (c:Currency)-[r:Arb*2]->(m)
WHERE c <> m
WITH x, REDUCE(s = startVal, e IN r | s * e.rate) AS endVal, startVal
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(x) | n) as Exchanges,
    extract ( e IN relationships(x) | startVal * e.rate) AS Rel,
    endVal, endVal - startVal AS Profit
ORDER BY Profit DESC LIMIT 5;
```

After using this query to create test data:

```
CREATE
  (c:Currency {name: 'One'})-[:Arb {rate:1}]->(h:Account {name: 'hop'})-[:Arb {rate:2}]->(t:Currency {name: 'Two'}),
  (t)-[:Arb {rate:3}]->(h)-[:Arb {rate:4}]->(c)
```

the above query produces these results:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Exchanges                                                     | Rel   | endVal | Profit |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [Node[8]{name:"Two"},Node[7]{name:"hop"},Node[6]{name:"One"}] | [3,4] | 12     | 11     |
| [Node[6]{name:"One"},Node[7]{name:"hop"},Node[8]{name:"Two"}] | [1,2] | 2      | 1      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Now the query returns [{"name":"Two"},{"name":"hop"}]   and other paths that ends on "hop" node. 

I can't have a path that ends on a "hop" node.

Comment: Works properly for me. I have edited my answer to show the results with test data.

Comment: I believe that the problem here is that the first line is not desired in the output. Maybe you should use a unique identifier in the first node of the pattern being `MATCH`ed, something like: `MATCH x = (c:Currency {id:1})-[r:Arb*2]->(m)`.

Comment: @dusktea Can you clarify whether my results are what you wanted? Also, which nodes have the `Currency` label?

Comment: @cybersam The results you posted are exactly what I want. 
In my case the "one" and "two" nodes are labeled :Currency, and the "hop" nodes are labeled :Account. Between two given currency nodes are at least one account "hop" node. But a "hop" node has only two Account nodes connected. I need to make a pattern where the nodes connected to a "hop" node are unique.

Comment: @dusktea I presume your last comment has a typo, and that a "hop" node has only two *Currency* nodes connected.

Comment: @dusktea I have updated my answer to give the "hop" node the `Account` label. It does not change my query results, though. Is the query sufficient?

Comment: It does make the nodes unique, but it splits the cycle in half. Is it possible to have "one"->"hop"->"two"->"hop"->"one" as an output?

Comment: If you replaced the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses with: `MATCH x = (c:Currency)-[r:Arb*4]->(c)`, then you'd get both full cycles (starting/ending at `One` and also at `Two`). If you really only want the cycle starting//ending at `One`, use `MATCH x = (c:Currency {name:'One'})-[r:Arb*4]->(c)`.

Comment: Will I be able to get the paths that are above 4 levels deep? If I specify r:Arb*4..100 my query hangs. 
Thanks again for your time!

Comment: A variable-length path search has exponential complexity. If the typical number of relationships per node is N, then a variable-length path search of depth D will require N**D operations and a correspondingly large amount of memory. So, you cannot use such a large range of lengths. But a much shorter range (maybe `[r:Arb*4..10]`) may work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question completely, but I believe that you problem can be solved putting a `WHERE` clause on the `MATCH` to prevent the not desired relationship be matched, like this:

```
WITH 1 AS startVal
MATCH x = (c:Currency)-[r:Arb*2]->(m)
WHERE NOT (m)-[:Arb]->(c)
WITH x, REDUCE(s = startVal, e IN r | s * e.rate) AS endVal, startVal
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(x) | n) as Exchanges,
    extract ( e IN relationships(x) | startVal * e.rate) AS Rel,
    endVal, endVal - startVal AS Profit
ORDER BY Profit DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: It still returns [{"name":"Two"},{"name":"hop"},{"name":"Two"}]. :(

What I am trying to do: 
Let node "One" is a start node. Next step would be "hop". When I am at "hop" I can go either to "One" node or "Two". Since I came from "one" node, I don't want to come back to it.  

Is there a way I could get a previous node, when I am at "hop" node and prune it from becoming the next node? Something like (n-1)<>(n+1)?

Comment: @dusktea Have you tried the cybersam solution? That is: put a `WHERE c <> m` after the `MATCH`. This way: `WITH 1 AS startVal
MATCH x = (c:Currency)-[r:Arb*2]->(m)
WHERE c <> m
WITH x, REDUCE(s = startVal, e IN r | s * e.rate) AS endVal, startVal
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(x) | n) as Exchanges,
    extract ( e IN relationships(x) | startVal * e.rate) AS Rel,
    endVal, endVal - startVal AS Profit
ORDER BY Profit DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: His solution makes my path end on "hop" node. Which is incorrect for me. Is there a way to make the path only consider nodes that are 2 relationships deep?

Comment: @dusktea The `:Currency` label is only in the One node?

Comment: :Currency label is for "One" and "two" node. "hop" node has label :Account